# Wait for unpredictable data before performing a completion a block inside method

Tags: swift

I have a function that does some work and call completion. Something like this

```
func doStuff(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
     performWork()
     completion(true)
}
```

The problem is that performWork triggers some process that receives result in other method. And depending on this result I need call `completion` with success or not based on data from previous method.

Is there any possible solution ? Method `doStuff` can not be modified and I don't have access to performWork() its third party, I can only call it.

Comment: Use a completion block for `performWork` as well and call `completion` in it.

Comment: "performWork triggers some process that receives result in other method" You mean that `performWork()` is async? Then add a completion handler on `performWork()`.

Comment: no I don't have access to performWork, its third party api

Comment: @AlexeyK Does that API have a delegate method that is called when the process is completed?

Comment: yes, it has delegate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save `completion` in a variable in the scope of your class and execute it in the delegate method of your API.

```
var doStuffCompletion: (Bool) -> ()!

func doStuff(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {
     performWork()
     doStuffCompletion = completion
}

func apiStuffFinished(success: Bool) {
    doStuffCompletion(success)
}
```